# Capture exceptions from Authorize attribute in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I have the added the [Authorise attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in my MVC4 application using Windows Authentication and while testing I changed the name of the active directory group to check that the `Application_Error` method in the Global.asax class would capture a non authorised user.

The problem is that the exception is not captured and IIS express throws a 401 exception. Can these type of authorisation exception be caught, if so are there better ways to handle exceptions in MVC application?

**Method**

[image]

**Global asax**

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

**IIS express throwing 401 unauthorised exception**

[image]

**Working validation**

Using this method works but its a little messy.

```
if (User.IsInRole(@"DOMAIN\USER"))
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges(model);
        ViewBag.Notification = "Save Successful";
    }
}
else
{
    throw new HttpException(404, "Category not found");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research I found a couple of blog posts from [Michael Mckenna](http://www.michael-mckenna.com/Blog) in [Part1](https://michael-mckenna.com/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1-our-options/) and [Part2](https://michael-mckenna.com/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc-part-2-our-options/) he details his exception handling strategy which I have got to work by manually testing is a user is in an active directory group and if not throwing an [HTTPException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This gets around the issue but still does not capture any exceptions when using the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

**Global.asax**

```
 protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;

        //Logging goes here

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";

        if (httpException != null)
        {
            switch(httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 401:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "NotAuthorised";
                    break;
                case 402:
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "NotAuthorised";
                    break;
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";
                    break;
            }

            Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
        }

        // Avoid IIS7 getting involved
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        // Execute the error controller
        IController errorsController = new Jmp.StaticMeasures.Controllers.ErrorController();
        HttpContextWrapper wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        var rc = new RequestContext(wrapper, routeData);
        errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }
```

**Error Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Jmp.StaticMeasures.Controllers
    {
        public class ErrorController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult NotFound()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult NotAuthorised()
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The default Authorize-attribute does not throw any exceptions. But like I suggested in my answer, You can easily implement a custom versionof the AuthorizeAttribute and just throw the required HTTPException from the HandleUnauthorizedRequest-method.

Comment: If I would assume that the 'HandleUnauthorizedRequest' method and specifically the 'actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse' line does wrap an exception in the response. Which the browser captures in the reponse header.

Comment: Those methods just send the 401 status code to the browser. They do not throw any exceptions which you could handle in your global error handler. I've modified my answer to include an example of a custom authorization attribute which throws the necessary exception.

Comment: new part2 link:
https://michaelm.azurewebsites.net/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc-part-2-our-implementation/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that AuthorizeAttribute throws any exceptions when it encounters an unauthorized request. It just sends the 401 response to the client.

If you want something else to happen, you can inherit from the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class and override the [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)-method. If you want an exception to be thrown, you can throw it from there.

```
public class ThrowingAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the AuthorizeAttribute sourcecode, so you can check what it does:

- https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs